# .htaccess redirect 301 using rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to beautify some urls. I configured the htaccess file so my urls are changed:

old url: http://mysite.com/index.php?id=45tye4
new url: http://mysite.com/45tye4

I want now to permanently redirect old urls to new urls. This is what I try with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?id=(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

The main problem seems to be the '?' in the url. When I try the same url without ? the redirect works. I also tried other variants with no luck:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php\?id=(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index.php[\?]id=(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

**Update:**

I added the redirection according to anubhava instructions. The redirection works, but unfortunately I get into a redirect loop. I thought [L] flag should solve the redirection loop, but it doesn't.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php/?$ /%1? [R=301,L] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule matches only REQUEST_URI. You have to use RewriteCond to match Query string

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&|\?)id=(.*)(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule . /%2? [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will redirect old URI of `/index.php?id=45tye4` to new URI: `/45tye4`

Comment: The redirection works, but unfortunately I get into a redirect loop. I thought [L] flag should solve the redirection loop, but it doesn't.

Comment: There was a minor typo, edited the answer. Please check again.

Comment: I added the updated one, still I get the redirect loop problem. I don't get it, shouldn't [L] flag avoid it?

Comment: I didn't notice your code in EDIT section earlier. Based on that I had to alter my answer. I have tested them and it is working fine. Please check.

Comment: I've updated it accordingly, still dosn't work. The redirection loop is broken but the 301 redirect does not work. For some strange reason the THE_REQUEST condition is not true for an url of type http://mysite.com/index.php?id=465.

Comment: Very strange, I have tested this above rule in my Linux, Mac and XAMPP installations and it is working everywhere.

Comment: I replaced the the_request condition with this one and it works now. I still don't know which is the problem. thanks for the help: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\ /index.php [NC]

Comment: Hmm other than not-escaping the dot `.` in `index.php` both versions look same but glad that it worked for you.